# Compatibility Mode Blackberry OS 4.7

Tags: blackberry, compatibility, blackberry-jde, virtual-keyboard

I am building an app using JDE 4.5. I need to support 4.5 device OS versions, I can't use JDE 4.7. Therefore, I can't use the Screen.getVirtualKeyBoard.setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE) in my code, as 4.5 doesn't support the virtual keyboard api.

I came across [this documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800719/What_Is_-_Compatibility_mode_on_touch_screen_BlackBerry_smartphones.html?nodeid=1487544&vernum=0) on setting compatility mode. The problem is I don't know where to set these values. All articles point out setting these values but don't describe how & where to set it. In my app, all I see is a Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml which has xml tags. Can someone please help me set these flags in my app?

Comment: Does not this sentence from your link "If the application is compiled with any earlier version of the BlackBerry JDE, it will run in compatibility mode" mean the application compiled with JDE 4.5 will run in compatibility mode? Of course you can't use API elements introduced in OS 4.7 when compiling or running on 4.5.

Comment: I understand that app built in version lower than 4.7 will run in compatibility mode. My question is how do I turn off the virtual keyboard if thats the case? I am thinking setting the flag in the JAD file(??) will do the trick. But the problem is I don't see a JAD file in my app. I see a Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml and I have no idea how to set the flag in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the values in the JAD (.jad) file that you put on the web server to enable OTA (over-the-air) deployment of the application. These values would be in addition to the usual RIM-Cod-URL and so on properties.

Creating a JAD file is quite simple. It's just a text file with name-value pairs of properties. There's a description [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Attributes_for_jad_files_513047_11.jsp) of all the various properties.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Clearly, I am a new to BlackBerry development. I am developing with Blackberry plugin for Eclipse. The link your provided mentions about using the Blackberry IDE. I was under the impression that I can package my app and submit to app world and be done. Can you please refer me to read up on OTA deployment and when & how I would do it?

Comment: I actually found the .jad file in the project deliverables folder and I added the compatibility values and it worked. thank you so much!